# Split number to ranges in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, range

I am trying to write a SQL query that show the distribution of customers seniority since 2015/01/31:

1. Up to one month
2. Between one and six months
3. Between six months and one year
4. Over a year

I succeeded to split and group the number of months of the customers.

```
SELECT Seniority, COUNT(Customer_ID) [Number of Customers]
FROM
(SELECT Customer_ID,
DATEDIFF(MONTH, MIN(CONVERT(datetime, Order_Date)), '2015/01/31') Seniority
FROM Orders
GROUP BY Customer_ID) t
GROUP BY Seniority
```

[image]

How can I split by given ranges?

Expected:

```
        Seniorty                |   Number of Customers
Up to one month                 |            0
Between one and six months      |            14
Between six months and one year |            1
Over a year                     |            0
```

Comment: Show us some sample _table data_, and the expected result - all as formatted test, no images.

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        'Up to one month' AS Seniority,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, Order_Date, '2015-01-31') < 1 THEN 1 END) AS [Number of Customers],
        1 AS position
    FROM Orders
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        'Between one and six months',
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, Order_Date, '2015-01-31') >= 1 AND
                        DATEDIFF(MONTH, Order_Date, '2015-01-31') < 6 THEN 1 END),
        2
    FROM Orders
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        'Between six months and one year',
         COUNT( CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, Order_Date, '2015-01-31') >= 6 AND
                        DATEDIFF(MONTH, Order_Date, '2015-01-31') < 12 THEN 1 END),
         3
    FROM Orders
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        'Over a year',
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, Order_Date, '2015-01-31') > 12 THEN 1 END),
        4
    FROM Orders
)

SELECT
    Seniority,
    [Number of Customers]
FROM cte
ORDER BY
    position;
```

This answer assumes that the `Order_Date` column is already date or datetime.  If not, then the first thing you should do is to convert this column to an actual date type.

Comment: I need the destribution of the seniority, how many customers are Up to one month, how muny customers are Between one and six months...

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,
           CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH,'2015-01-31',ORDER_DATE)=1 THEN 'Up to one month'
               WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH,'2015-01-31',ORDER_DATE) BETWEEN 1 AND 6 THEN 'Between one and six months'
               WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH,'2015-01-31',ORDER_DATE) BETWEEN 6 AND 12 THEN 'Between six months and one year'
               WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH,'2015-01-31',ORDER_DATE)>12 THEN 'Over a year'
           END AS SENIORITY
      FROM ORDERS 
     )
SELECT SENIORITY AS 'Seniority', COUNT(CUSTOMER_ID) AS 'Number of Customers'
FROM CTE
WHERE SENIORITY IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY SENIORITY
```

Comment: . . I have no idea why this would be downvoted.  The answer is better than the other answer.  You are new to the site, but you should learn about how to format your answers so they look better.